# QML module not installed error: running Qt app on Embedded Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to launch my cross-compiled GUI Qt application on a certain TI board.
I use this command to launch the application:

```
QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/root/qt-5.2.1-install/plugins LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/root/qt-5.2.1-install/lib/ ./simple_qml_ui -platform linuxfb
```

Unfortunately the error occurs:

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/root/qt_app/styles" ... 
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/root/qt-5.2.1-install/plugins/styles" ... 
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component 
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:3 module "QtQuick.Window" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:1 module "QtQuick" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" is not installed
qrc:/main.qml:4 module "QtQuick.Dialogs" is not installed
```

Am I missing some important deployment step? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you just need to copy plugins directory from your Qt installation folder to your app folder.

Comment: Do you mean the "plugins" directory or the "qml" directory?
See also http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-imports.html#qml-import-path

Answer (score 4):

This answer does not match the topic creators plattform, but i recently had the same error under windows and found this question.

So for other people who have this problem under windows there is the following solution:

```
.\windeployqt.exe <project-path> --release --qmldir <qml-dir>
```

qml-dir example: C:\Qt\5.11.0\mingw53_32\qml

in my case i had to additionally copy the following dlls from the \bin folder:

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll, libstdc++-6.dll, libwinpthread-1.dll
```